# Oracle cleaning up duplicate records

Tags: oracle

We have a "document archive" storage table that looks like this:

```
FD_RID   KEYWORD  VALUE                    INSUSER  INSDATE
93771    CRID     892448                   CC3      10/25/2005 3:47:09 PM
93771    CRID     892448                   CC3      11/1/2005 12:08:23 PM
93771    DATE     20060101                 CC3      10/25/2005 3:47:09 PM
93771    DATE     20060101                 CC3      11/1/2005 12:08:23 PM
93771    DIST     INT                      AHZ      11/2/2007 11:32:24 AM
93771    DNAME    CDues Inv                CC3      10/25/2005 3:47:09 PM
93771    DNAME    CDues Inv                CC3      11/1/2005 12:08:23 PM
93771    FNAME    \892448\CDues\2006CDues  CC3      10/21/2005 5:11:43 PM
93771    RDATE    20051021                 CC3      10/25/2005 3:47:09 PM
93771    RDATE    20051021                 CC3      11/1/2005 12:08:23 PM
```

That is the "record" for one single document. Think of this as a kind of tuple table where we have multiple "columns" that are defined by the KEYWORDs. A document may have more, less or even different KEYWORDs than above.
We have 30,000,000 records in the table and literally thousands of records where we have duplicate entries like the ones above,  CRID, DNAME, RDATE. The rows may also have different VALUE(s), just duplicate KEYWORDs.

I need to remove the oldest, by INSDATE, records that have duplicate keywords. I have the code below to delete ALL duplcate rows but I am not sure if it will delete the records if it havs a different VALUE or it will delete the oldest of the 2 duplicates.

```
DELETE FROM fkp_archive WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT MYROWID FROM (
        SELECT rowid MYROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER 
                                                    ORDER BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER, 
                                                             FKP_INSDATE DESC) RN
        FROM fkp_archive
    ) WHERE RN > 1
)
```

Is there any way to improve the code above so that I can delete the duplcates by passing in the KEYWORD that I want to clean up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **first thing** when you fight dups is to define what is your (missing) **primary key**.

This could be

```
FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD,FKP_VALUE,FKP_INSUSER
```

if you tolerate duplicated values in the same keyword stored by different authors.

If you will enforce a unique value for a KEYWORD and RID, this would be only

```
FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD
```

In further I use your PK with 4 columns, but pls re-check the requirement.
**Use this column list in your GROUP BY / PARTITION BY clause below**

Next step is to **check the dups**.

```
select FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD,FKP_VALUE,FKP_INSUSER, count(*) -1 dup_cnt
from fkp_archive
group by FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER
having count(*) > 1
order by 5 desc;

FKP_FD_RID FKP_KEYWORD  FKP_VALUE   USER CNT
93771        CRID           892448      CC3 1
93771        DATE           20060101      CC3   1
93771        RDATE        20051021    CC3   1
93771        DNAME         CDues Inv    CC3 1
```

The sum of the last column gives the total number of dups - i.e. records you want to get rid off.

Depending on the total count, you may decide to reorganize the table as proposed in other answer (CTAS). If this is not an option, 
you may remove the dups stepwise.

Here an example to clean the first two keywords, simple by limiting the subquery.
Use the previous query to get the number of records that will be processed. You may also rund the subquery only to get impression of the time you will need to run the delete.

```
DELETE FROM fkp_archive WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT MYROWID FROM (
        SELECT rowid MYROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER 
                                                    ORDER BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER, 
                                                             FKP_INSDATE DESC) RN
        FROM fkp_archive
        where FKP_FD_RID = 93771 and FKP_KEYWORD in ('CRID','DNAME')  /* Limit the scope here */
    ) WHERE RN > 1
)
;
```

This will remove the first two dups, adapt the query to remove the rest.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood or maybe I don't understand what you are saying. I want to pass a KEYWORD and have it clean up the oldest duplicate by KEYWORD.

Comment: @MB34 I got your point, I completely reformulate the answer - hopefully in more clean matter

Answer (score 0):

If you are partitioning by the key fields, then your order by will just be the date field you're using to determine the "older" records:

```
DELETE FROM fkp_archive WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT MYROWID FROM (
        SELECT rowid MYROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER 
                                                    ORDER BY FKP_INSDATE DESC) RN
        FROM fkp_archive
    ) WHERE RN > 1
)
```

That said, if you have 30 million rows, and a lot of duplicates, then I'd probably do a CTAS to remove the dups.  A large number of deletes, especially while maintaining indexes, will be painful in most cases (and slow).  You'll also have to worry about snapshot too old issues depending on how long it takes.

Try something like:

```
-- create new table (CTAS)
create table fkp_archive2 
tablespace mytablespace
-- other storage info here

as
SELECT * FROM fkp_archive WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT MYROWID FROM (
        SELECT rowid MYROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD, FKP_VALUE, FKP_INSUSER 
                                                    ORDER BY FKP_INSDATE DESC) RN
        FROM fkp_archive
    ) WHERE RN = 1
);
-- TEST new fkp_archive2 to be sure its what you want!
--
-- add back any default column values to fkp_archive2
--
-- DO FOLLOWING IN MAINTENANCE WINDOW
-- drop existing fkp_archive, rename fkp_archive2 -> fkp_archive
-- add indexes/grants/synonyms/etc, generate stats...
```

Comment: We intend to do it in a loop of only 1000 records at a time with commits.

Comment: how many rows will be deleted?  Also, if looping in pl/sql and selecting across commits, you can still get snapshot too old.  If a large number of deletes, seriously consider the CTAS approach (other benefits too, like resetting HWM).  Good luck

Comment: Looks like I have approx 1,081,880 duplicates.

Comment: For 1 in 30 records being deleted, I'd just run the delete and not bother with a more complex CTAS process.